# Create a link to js file with js

Tags: javascript

I have the below js. which is also in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/QLA7A/)

```
    (function () {
        var test = document.createElement('script');
        test.type = 'text/javascript';
        test.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.example.com/test.js';
        console.log(test);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeEnd", test);
    })();
```

I want to put the js at the bottom of my page just before the closing js tags.

When I view it in the console.log I get the expected result.
Which is

```
<script type=​"text/​javascript" src=​"http:​/​/​www.example.com/​test.js">​</script>​
```

However when I try and actually add it to my page I get [object HTMLScriptElement]

What am I missing here or is there another method I can try to acheive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML) takes html as its argument not dom nodes. I'd use appendChild instead

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(test);
```

Comment: `appendChild` also has the benefit of having universal browser support, which isn't the case for `insertAdjacentHTML`.

Answer (score 2):

I took a slightly different approach and tried appending the script as a child of the body node. Here's an example using your code:

```
(function (document) {
    var test = document.createElement('script');
    test.type = 'text/javascript';
    test.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'www.example.com/test.js';
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(test);
})(document);
```

It seems to get the desired result.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think 'beforeend' needs to be all lowercase.

`[...]
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", test);`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML

Look above for Musa's answer, which is the correct insertion method in this case.